# Cout does not work - (error: no match for ‘operator<<’)

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to learn c++. I have understood few things.

I was trying to implement program using vector in c++ for dynamic array, while everything seems to work but one thing in particular `cout` statement throws some weird error .

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector> 

using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 
    vector<int> g1; 

    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        g1.push_back(i); 
    }

    cout << "This works"; // this cout works

    cout << g1; // but this does not why ?

    return 0;
}
```

Error that I am getting after running.

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:18:7: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ and ‘std::vector<int>’)
  cout << g1;
  ~~~~~^~~~~
```

Here is the program. I was trying to debug on hackerrank and I came across this problem. 
Why does not cout work for vector variable only? What am I missing?

Comment: You are not missing anything. There is no `operator<<` implemented for `vector<T>`. You'll have to implement it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for replying, how would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no overload for `operator<<` for `std::vector<T>`. If you *really* wish to use `operator<<` for `std::vector<T>`, you will have to provide the implementation for it yourself, eg:

```
template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const std::vector<T>& vec) {
  if ( !vec.empty() ) {
    out << '{';
    std::copy (std::cbegin(vec), 
               std::cend(vec), 
               std::ostream_iterator<T>(out, ", "));
    out << "}";
  }
  return out;
}
```

<kbd>[`Demo Here`](https://rextester.com/RSLJS36017)</kbd>

Comment: It will work for toy programs, but it breaks easily because it's not in `namespace std`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d56aaaaba45b8d41

Comment: This is little overwhelming but this is what I was looking for thanks

Comment: @HolyBlackCat can't put the overload inside `namespace NS`  ?

Comment: @P0W You can, but you also can have more than one namespace. I guess you could add `using NS::operator<<;` in every namespace that needs it, but that's not very convenient.

Answer (score 0):

`cout` is a stream. You can write all the integral types (`int`, `long`, `char`, `short`, pointers etc.) and `string` to a stream, but `vector` is unsupported. If you want to print it, you may want to iterate through elements like this:

```cpp
for (int i: g1) {
    cout << i << ' ';
}
```

Or you can also implement `operator<<` for vector:

```cpp
template <typename T> ostream& operator<<(ostream& lhs, vector<T> rhs) {
    for (T i: rhs) {
         lhs << i;
    }
    return lhs;
}
```

Then you will be able to use `cout << g1;`.

Comment: Would you please ellaborate a little?

Comment: @waqar Printing the entire vector at once is not allowed, you have to loop over it to print it.

Comment: Okay I had a function , say hoo(vector<int> arr) {cout << arr; // I wanted to see this array before  implementing the actual program}

Answer (score 0):

You need to print vector like below code snippet:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector> 

using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 
    vector<int> g1; 

    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        g1.push_back(i); 
    }

    cout << "This works"; // this cout works

    for (int i = 0; i < g1.size(); ++i)
        cout << g1[i] << ' ';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So I can't see "vector" array altogether?

Comment: g1 is your vector which you have declared. I iterated the vector until the length and cout the desired items.